# Why won't factoring lead to the same result as expanding when simplifying $(x+y)^2 - y^2 - x^2 + 2xy$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Hello I was trying to simplify and solve the following equation: $(x+y)^2 - y^2 - x^2 + 2xy$

My first approach was to factor the difference in squares leading to

$$(x+y)^2 - (y+x)(y-x) + 2xy $$

Then factor out $(x+y)$:$$(x+y)\cdot((x+y)-(y-x)) + 2xy$$

and then simplify: $$(x+y)\cdot(2x)+2xy = 2x^2 + 4xy$$

However, when actually expanding $(x+y)^2$ and then simplifying the result is only $4xy$:

$$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - y^2 - x^2 + 2xy = 4xy$$

Why will those methods lead to two different equations? Did I break a rule of algebra? Normally I thought this should lead to an outcome that is equal. Is there any rule when simplification by expansion would be favored over factoring?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The part "$\dots-y^2 - x^2\dots$" is not a difference of squares, because no real number has square $-y^2$

Comment: be careful next time, $(x+y)^2 - y^2 - x^2 + 2xy=(x+y)^2 - (y^2 + x^2) + 2xy\neq(x+y)^2 -( y^2 - x^2) + 2xy$

Comment: $(x+y)^2 - y^2 - x^2 + 2xy$ is not an equation. It doesn't have an "$=$" sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x+y)^2 \color{green}{- y^2 - x^2} + 2xy=(x+y)^2  \color{red}{-(y+x)(y-x)} + 2xy \tag 1$$

It is a wrong claim,
$$RHS{=(x+y)^2 - (y+x)(y-x) + 2xy\\
=(x+y)^2 - (y^2-x^2) + 2xy\\
=(x+y)^2 - y^2+x^2 + 2xy\ne LHS}$$

& $$\color{green}{- y^2 - x^2}\ne \color{red}{-(y+x)(y-x)}$$